# What does it mean by a density argument?

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question

When I read some books, it states "a density argument", what does it mean? When applying to symmetric function, what does it mean?

Comment: It is difficult to answer without a precise context, but usually "by a density argument" means that you had proved a statement for all elements $x$ in a dense subset $A$ of a topological set $X$, and you extend the statement to the whole $X$ using density. For example, if you prove that a continuous function $f$ is constant on a dense subset $A$ of $X$, then $f$ is constant on all $x$ by density.

Answer (score 6):

For the sake of an answer (thanks to the comment above):

> It is difficult to answer without a precise context, but usually "by a density argument" means that you had proved a statement for all elements $x$ in a dense subset $A$ of a topological set $X$, and you extend the statement to the whole $X$ using density. For example, if you prove that a continuous function $f$ is constant on a dense subset $A$ of $X$, then $f$ is constant on $X$ by density.

Comment: It may mean many other things. It may be that the author verifies the existence of a point with some property by actually checking that the collection of such points is dense (rather than by actually exhibiting an example).

Comment: Definitely. This technique is used almost everywhere in PDE theory for instance.